Trying to install Maui on Mac: How can I solve the .Net workload version 8.0.401-baseline.24412.2 not found problem?
I'm trying install the maui workload along with the .net workloads on Mac using the terminal, and I keep getting this problem of Unhandled exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Workload version 8.0.401-baseline.24412.2 was not found.
after installing the .net SDK and workloads I got a warning of : Workload garbage collection failed with error: Workload version 8.0.401-baseline.24412.2 was not found..
tried cleaning, repairing, updating, clearing the SDK path, uninstalling, and installing again but the problem persists and prevents me from creating a new project. Any help is much appreciated.

In the terminal, what command do you use to install the .net workload?

I installed the latest .net sdk version from their webpage which is 8.0.401, then used this line in the terminal : sudo dotnet workload install maui
I also tried : sudo dotnet workload install maui-android maui-ios

If you enter dotnet --version in the terminal, does the command line display the version of .Net you have installed?

Is your Xcode version 15.4?

I fixed the problem by downloading .net 9 preview version of the .net sdk , uninstalled the 8.0.402 version and installed the new one.

I found this issue in dotnet GitHub ([NETSDKE2E]With 8.0.400 SDK zip installed, warning and Error).
This is a confirmed bug: Currently, both .NET 8.0.400 and 8.0.401 will show Warning: "Workload garbage collection failed with error: Workload version 8.0.400-baseline.24372.6 was not found...".
Member stated in the issue that this issue was fixed in SDK 8.0.402, and I checked the .NET8.0 version list and did not find 8.0.402, so I judged that this version has not been released yet. You can post a comment in this issue to ask for the specific release date.

yes exactly, thanks for the help. I fixed the problem by downloading .net 9 preview version of the .net sdk , uninstalled the 8.0.402 version and installed the new one.

ok, it is also a solution.

Yes , thank you Shuowen He .
